# converting RIchText to Mime in java using domino designer

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, domino-designer-eclipse

Hi guys i am working Inline attachments(like images inside a mail body) in lotus notes.Based on the guidance on this question([can anyone please tell how to deal with inline images in lotus notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280172/can-anyone-please-tell-how-to-deal-with-inline-images-in-lotus-notes).I) am trying to convert the Mail body from Richtext to MIME using.Domino version is 8.5.3

```
m_session.setConvertMIME(false);

doc.removeItem("$KeepPrivate");

doc.convertToMIME(doc.CVT_RT_TO_HTML,0);

MIMEEntity me=doc.getMIMEEntity("body");
```

The code is working fine when tried with agent.But when deployed in the server i am getting

```
NotesException: Conversion To MIME Failed:
[1FD8:0047-1DDC] 12-02-2014 18:30:23   HTTP JVM: HTMLAPI Problem converting to HTML.
```

When i searched all the material is saying this is a problem with lotus notes.can anyone please tell how to fix this.or is there any work around for this.Please help

Answer (score 3):

I got a working **RichText > Mime** conversion script in **ssjs**, I guess this could be adapted to Java

```js
function convertBodyToMimeAndSave(documentToConvert){

  // Create a temporary document
  // Calling convertToMime makes a MIME output of the full
  /// document and puts it in body. If you have other
  // fields than body in the original document, that 
  // will produce undesirable added content to the body
  var tmp = database.createDocument();

  // Put the original richtext in it 
  var rt = targetDocument.getFirstItem("Body")
  if(!rt) return targetDocument
  rt.copyItemToDocument(tmp)

  // Convert the temporary document to MIME
  tmp.convertToMIME(2)

  // Copy all Items (that is, the Body) back to the original document
  // (copying the Body specifically seemed to make the script crash)
  tmp.copyAllItems (targetDocument, true)


  targetDocument.closeMIMEEntities(true, "Body")
  targetDocument.save()
}
```